# Client Denied by Server Configuration and Apache Error log

Tags: magento2

I upgraded Magento 2 and trying to access the website, but I'm getting the error below...

```
This site can’t be reached. unexpectedly closed the connection. Try Checking the connection, Checking the proxy and the firewall, ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I have run all Magento permissions
Changed folders and files ownership

This is the error I found in Apache error log

```
[Thu Mar 31 19:26:40.740419 2022] [authz_core:error] [pid 20493] [client 45.155.204.146:59076] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/.../public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Double check your Apache httpd.conf and VirtualHost conf file (if you have one) that the DocumentRoot for the site is correct.

You may also have to update access rules.

```
<Directory />
 AllowOverride none
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /Path/to/Your/Site>
 AllowOverride none
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[Apache2 Documentation for the error code](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=115522258#content/view/115522258)

Edit: Wanted to add that the access rules may vary slightly depending on which version of Apache you’re running.

Be careful when changing ownership and permissions on your site’s directory hierarchy and files that you haven’t exposed sensitive things to the public.

Comment: I already have the script below in the .htaccess file. Do I have to use yours as well? "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

Comment: That's a rewrite rule for your URL. If you want to test whether it's causing the problem, you can either comment out the <IfModule> block in the file or rename the file temporarily. I don't suspect it's causing the rejected connection error though. What does your Apache VirtualHost conf file look like for the site?

Comment: Check the Magento error logs too—they may give you a better idea of what’s going on, in case it’s a Magento config problem and not Apache.

Comment: I think the problem is with the .htaccess file. Unfortunately, Magento is only generating error in the system.log file in var folder, which is only about cron job. But I think this issue is not related to the cron job. Here is the error I found again in Apache error log: "[client 172.70.114.106:60612] /home/.../public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: https://hello.example.com/

Comment: You might have to turn Magento logging on—it’s disabled by default. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/logging.html Take the <Directory> block out of htaccess. Check the main Apache conf file. It should be like /etc/…/apache2.conf or httpd.conf (depends on the system). There will already be a <Directory> block toward the end of that file… make sure it looks similar to what I posted (make a backup copy of the conf file before futzing with it).

Comment: Oh, and you’ll need to ‘systemctl reload apache’ if you update the conf.

Comment: <Directory />
 AllowOverride none
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /Path/to/Your/Site>
 AllowOverride none
 Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Right, but `/Path/to/Your/Site` is only an example. You'd need the actual path to the directory serving your Magento2 installation. Based on the Apache error it will be something like `/home/.../public_html`. Note that this is only a relative (`...`) path. Navigating to that public_html directory and typing `pwd` will show full non-relative path. Were you serving a working Magento installation from this same machine in the past?

Comment: Adding "AllowOverride All" to Apache's "post_virtualhost_global.confGlobal" file seems to resolve the .htaccess issue. However, I'm getting permission error again. I have ran all Magento folder and file permission. but still getting permission error, "The stream or file \"/home/.../public_html//var/log/system.log\" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied at /home/.../public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:110)"} []

Comment: Are you sure that log file has write permission for whatever user / group owns the Magento installation? Try chmod 664 if 644 isn't sufficient.

Comment: Your suggested have really helped in troubleshooting the issue... Running the account and user ownership again has resolved the problem... Thank you!